# Functions in PHP

Tags: php

I am battling with a php function.

I am trying to create a function that accepts 5 arguments. 
The user needs to select the activity of they choice, a message with the activity of their choice should be echoed back to the user.

I used an array and a foreach statement within the function but it doesn't work.

Please help

```
<?php
// Declare the function and variables

error_reporting (0);
$msg = "";
$activity = "";

function activites ($paintballing , $ice_skating, $horse_riding, $para_gliding,    $water_rafting ){

    // Make the activity array

    $activites = array (1=> 'Paintballing', 'Ice_skating', 'Horse_riding', 'para_gliding', 'water_rafting');

    // make the activity  pull down menu
    echo '<select name ="activity">';

    // use a foreach loop to loop through the activity

     foreach ($activites as $key =>$value) {
    echo "<option value \"key\"$key\">$value</option>\n";

}

}

if ($activity == ""){
    $msg = "<font color = 'red'> Please select an activity from the drop down   menu</font>";

 }

?>



<html>
<head>
<title>Function </title>
</head>
<body>
 <center> <a href="index.php">Home </a>  |  <a href ="calc.php">Calc</a> | <a    href="string.php">String</a> | <a href ="array.php"> Array </a> | <a href =   "function.php">Function </a></center>
  </center>

 <form name = 'function' method = "POST" action = 'function.php' >

 <p>Select one of the activity you would like to do today:</p>

   <select name="Activity" size="5">
   <option selected value = "">
   <option> Paintballing </option>
   <option> Ice-skating </option>
    <option> Horse-riding </option>
   <option> Para-gliding </option>
   <option> Water-rafting </option>
  </select>
   </form>
  <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" />
  </option>
  <?php echo $msg;?>
  <p align ="center"><a href ="function.txt" Onclick ="window.open ('function.txt', 'function', resizable =no, height=500, width=500, scrollercars=yes'); retrun   false;">Function.txt</a></p>
```

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: `$activites = array (1=> $paintballing, $ice_skating, $horse_riding', $para_gliding', $water_rafting');`

Comment: Do you actually call this function somewhere?

Comment: @Allendar is saying that is not correct syntax.  Need either  `$activites = array ('Paintballing', ...` or  `$activites = array (1=> array('Paintballing', ...`  Also, You should be getting error messages no?

Comment: His array is fine the way he defined it. He is just setting the first numeric key and the keys after that will be 2, 3, 4. He is just initializing they array starting at 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the function

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    echo activities($_POST['Activity']);
}
```

Your function modified

```
function activities($activity) {
    $activities = array(
            'Paintballing',
            'Ice_skating',
            'Horse_riding',
            'para_gliding',
            'water_rafting'
    );
    $activity = trim($activity);
    if (! in_array($activity, $activities))
        return false;

    return sprintf("You have selected : %s", $activity);
}
```

Comment: Also, `activites` is `activities` misspelled, you might want to fix that while your code's small.

Comment: @PedroCordeiro .. yeah i know ... i should have corrected it myself ... :)